# Cannot find the symmetric key '', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, encryption

Using SQL 2005

I created a Master Key encrypted by password and then encrypted the Master Key with the Service Master Key

I then created an ASYMMETRIC_KEY which I use to encrypt my SYMMETRIC_KEY I did all this using the SA user for SQL and logged into windows server as the domain admin.

I have a user in my database that only has dbo permissions on my database and then I grant that user execute permissions on all the necessary stored procedures and I also deny view definition to those same stored procedures.

The stored procedure giving me trouble where I do the encryption is this here. Also this all worked on SQL2012 in my testing pc but now that I am creating this on production server with sql 2005 and it is failing

```
open symmetric key
    MYKEY_NAME_SYM decryption by Asymmetric key MYKEY_NAME_ASYM
    set @ENCRYPTVARIABLE = (select ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('MYKEY_NAME_SYM'), @ENCRYPTCOLUMN))    
close symmetric key MYKEY_NAME_SYM
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
Cannot find the symmetric key 'MKEY_NAME_SYM', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

So I am guessing that the user I am using in my database does not have permissions but when I try to grant permissions

```
GRANT 
VIEW DEFINITION ON SYMMETRIC KEY::MKEY_NAME_SYM TO [myuser]
```

I get the same error cannot find the symmetric key or I don't have permissions.

Comment: I had some problems with permissions and I think `ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY` fixed it.

Comment: Yes I ran that command also but I am still receiving the error. I have a feeling it has something to do with my database user that has permissions to my storedprocedures but not the keys. But when I try to grant that user permissions to my encryption keys it says I don't have permissions to do that and Im using the SA account of sql

Comment: Have a look at [this MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179887.aspx). I'm pretty sure I had to grant REFERENCES as well ...

Comment: Thanks but it will not allow me to grant any permissions at all it fails saying I do not have permissions even though I am using the same user that I created the keys with

Answer (score 24):

With an administrative user write in script console:

```
    --Grant View
    GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON CERTIFICATE::[Certificate_Name] TO [user]
    GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SYMMETRIC KEY::[EncryptionKey_Name] TO [user]

    --Grant Control
    GRANT CONTROL ON CERTIFICATE::[Certificate_Name] TO [user]
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed to switch SQL to use windows authentication as the only user that had permissions was the domain\admin user which is the user I created the key with.

Once I switched to windows authentication I was then able to grant permissions to the Keys and all was good

Answer (score 2):

One thing I haven't seen others mention: To create a login from a symmetric or asymmetric key, the key and the login must both be created in the MASTER database.

Example:

```
USE MASTER
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.asymmetric_keys where name = 'MySecret.AsymmetricKey') BEGIN
    CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY [AsymmetricKey]
    FROM FILE='C:\temp\MyStrongNameKey.snk'
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from sys.sql_logins where name = 'StrongNameKeyLogin') BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [StrongNameKeyLogin] 
    FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY [AsymmetricKey]
END
GO

-- If necessary, do this here:
GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO [StrongNameKeyLogin] 

USE [MyDatabase]
-- Now you can create assemblies, or do whatever else you need that references the signed login
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sql Server 2012, we had to change @Paul Smith's answer just a little bit.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from sys.sql_logins where name = 'StrongNameKeyLogin') BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [StrongNameKeyLogin] 
    FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY [AsymmetricKey]
END
```

Did not work for us, but changing `sys.sql_logins`
to `sys.server_principalswhere` seam to do the trick.

As in:

````
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from sys.server_principalswhere name = 'StrongNameKeyLogin') BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [StrongNameKeyLogin] 
    FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY [AsymmetricKey]
END```
````

Answer (score 0):

The below line solved for me.

```
import CryptoKit
```